# A weak inequality than Hurwitz

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

How can i prove that among any two consecuent convergents to x, al least one of the satisfy $|x-h_{n}/k_{n}|$ $< 1/2k_{n}^2$

I know, by the Thoerem of Hurwitz, that among any three consecutive convegents one of them (al least) satisfy a stronger inequality, but, what if this is the convergent that is out of our selection in the two consecutive for the weak inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of two consecutive convergents, one is smaller than $x$, the other is greater than $x$, so

$$\left\lvert x - \frac{h_n}{k_n}\right\rvert + \left\lvert x-\frac{h_{n+1}}{k_{n+1}}\right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{h_n}{k_n} - \frac{h_{n+1}}{k_{n+1}}\right\rvert.$$

Now see that the right hand term is smaller than $\frac{1}{2 k_n^2} + \frac{1}{2k_{n+1}^2}$.